# Answering a Protected Riddle

Tags: discussion

Isn't it somewhat restrictive to require 10 rep for a challenging puzzle that gets protected?  If puzzling members are struggling to come up with the right answer, why would you want to limit the involvement of new users with less than 10 rep?  Couldn't they potentially shed fresh light on the subject?

I realize it's likely new users might have a lower quality answer with an incomplete explanation, but why not have a minimum answer length instead of the rep requirement?

*this question probably fits better in the puzzling meta

Comment: One option is to create an account on another stackexchange site and then create your account here using the previous account. BAM! +100rep.

Comment: @Danny [Not really.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: Do you have an example of a question you'd like to answer, but can't?

Comment: @Jon OP did mean [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/the-bigger-i-am-the-less-i-will-hold-who-or-what-am-i).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the minimum-length requirement.

This would just give *long* spam answers. So far, SE has been reasonably clean of spam to my experience, which is an achievement in itself!

I think "earning 10 rep" is not a very hard threashold if you're interested in a topic. IMHO, "discouraging one-time-shot-answer-browse-in-users" is the far better option than "inviting spam".

If the user was really only interested in "answering this one quickly" (And it is a protected question already for a reason!) then we quite likely *do not want this answer*. And, quite often, we don't want the puzzle neither. At least not see it further boosted by tons of surf-in-one-shots.

Comment: Then how do you earn 10 rep if you find five questions to answer, all of which are protected? Are suggested edits as common here as on more objective SE sites?

Comment: @DamianYerrick Find a 'non protected' question ;c) Broadly speaking, "protected" is not the norm, but the exception. And generally speaking, for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The 10-rep requirement to answer protected questions is the Stack Exchange  network wide. In case you have a Community-protected question in mind (maybe [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/the-bigger-i-am-the-less-i-will-hold-who-or-what-am-i)?), then [the reason is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/52765#52765):

> The system (via the Community user) will automatically protect a question that's had three answers from low-rep users deleted or 5 answers from low-rep users posted in the past 24 hours.

(i.e. there are five answers from new users which haven't got upvotes)

This happens because system gets afraid that the answers could be from spammers.

Your idea is nice, though I doubt this will be enforced just on Puzzling.

---

Just by the way, I'd say that the linked question should be unprotected.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - I'm pretty sure I have the answer to [The bigger I am...](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35288/the-bigger-i-am-the-less-i-will-hold-who-or-what-am-i)

Comment: @Andrew I've solved the puzzle about getting the question you want to answer :D